Prestashop 1.7.6 custom module - order status change problem
I have a problem with custom module to prestashop 1.7.6. I try to change order status - it works fine but sometimes it dosn't trigger hookActionOrderStatusPostUpdate
This is my loop to change order state.
        foreach ($ordersIds as $orderId) {
            $order = new Order($orderId);
            if($order->current_state != $newStatusId) { 
                $history = new OrderHistory();      
                $history->id_order = (int)$order->id;
                $history->changeIdOrderState($newStatusId, $order);
                $history->addWithemail(true);
                $history->save();
            }
        }

Sometimes there is a problem that order status is changed properly, but hookActionOrderStatusPostUpdate was not triggered.

I think you're using the wrong hook.
The actionOrderStatusPostUpdate hook is triggered before new OrderStatus() is saved to the database. You should use the actionOrderHistoryAddAfter hook instead.
More details on the hooks are available on the Prestashop developer documentation:
https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/

Even it's triggered before it still should be triggered. But there is a problem that sometimes is triggered and sometimes not. I also try this:
$order = new Order($orderId); $order->setCurrentState($newStatusId);  but it's the same problem.
